# physically closing a file in python as if i pressed the x button on a txt file

Tags: python

so I'm new to python and I figured out how to open a file using `os.startfile`, but I can't seem to find the function to close a file as if I physically pressed the x button on a txt file.

anybody know what the function is for that?

Comment: What's with the downvotes? Read the question.

Comment: Don't you mean virtually press? There is no physical button. You don't physically press anything. Except the mouse.

Comment: @Jerry Mar, are you saying you want to close the file when a user actually closes the file or what exactly?

Comment: this is os.dependent ... you can use `os.kill` maybe...

Comment: Note that `os.startfile` could launch any application, there is no safe way to tell which is being launched, so even if you could close the application after launching it (which you can’t), you wouldn’t know which.

Comment: I'm just a noob...I'm not too surprised if I got downvotes for a question...sorry if I didn't word it properly. I did do research but I guess I didn't understand the answer below as there isn't a function that exists for closing the file.

Comment: @ Padraic Cunningham yep, that's what I'm saying...I would like the file to be closed if it was physically opened through python...not me closing the file because what if I forget to close it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't that way.

As described in the python documentation : https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.startfile

> startfile() returns as soon as the associated application is launched. There is no option to wait for the application to close, and no way to retrieve the application’s exit status. The path parameter is relative to the current directory. If you want to use an absolute path, make sure the first character is not a slash ('/'); the underlying Win32 ShellExecute() function doesn’t work if it is. Use the os.path.normpath() function to ensure that the path is properly encoded for Win32.

What do you intend to do actually, as there may be other ways to reach your goal ?

Comment: someone already posted this exact answer and got downvotes and deleted their answer ...  (that said imho this answers the question)

Answer (score -3):

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_close.htm

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# Open a file
fo = open("foo.txt", "wb")
print "Name of the file: ", fo.name
# Close opend file
fo.close()
```